# How To display the line chart with chart.js in react?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I take reference from [here](https://medium.com/codex/data-visualization-with-react-js-and-chart-js-cb6ca5d77ff6). By following her steps, I can execute my BarChart. But when I try to change it into LineChart, some errors appear.

[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3dad.png)
[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKXZB.png)

The LineChart Code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Chart as ChartJS, CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend,} from 'chart.js'
import  {Line} from "react-chartjs-2"
// Radar, Doughnut, Polar, Pie
import axios from 'axios';

ChartJS.register(
    CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend
);


function LineChart() {
    const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({datasets: [],});
    const Chart = () => {
        let Cost = [];
        let No = [];

        axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/TranscationRecord/Cost")
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            for(const dataObj of res.data){
                Cost.push(parseInt(dataObj.Cost));
                const d = new Date(dataObj.StartD);
                No.push(d.toLocaleDateString('en-us',{day:"2-digit",month:"2-digit" }));
            }

            setChartData({
                labels: No,
                type:'line',
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Daily Cost',
                    data: Cost,
                    backgroundColor:'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                }],
            });

        })

        .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err);
        })     
    }

    useEffect(() => {Chart();}, []);
   
    return(
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Line Chart</h1>
            <div>
                <Line data = { chartData }/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }

  export default LineChart;
```

I try to find and solve the problem, and I know that there are some problems in

`setChartData({ datasets:[{}] })`

```
setChartData({
            labels: No,
            type:'line',
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Daily Cost',
                data: Cost,
                backgroundColor:'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                borderWidth: 1,
            }],
        });
```

Therefore, I qoute the `datasets:{}` into `data{}`

```
setChartData({
            labels: No,
            type:'line',
            data:{
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Daily Cost',
                    data: Cost,
                    backgroundColor:'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                }],
            }
        });
```

No error appear but it can not display the LineChart
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJjn9.png).

Why would this happen, and how can I solve it?

Comment: why you don't use `useEffect` when fetching data and setstate there ?!

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says you don't import and register the `PointElement`. For line charts you also will need to import and register the `LineElement` after that like you did for the barElemekt, legend etc